# Firebase: allow anyone from an array of UIDs to access read / write

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm developing an app using Firebase's Realtime Database and need to allow multiple users to access the same data, but I'm having trouble figuring out a security rule that makes this work.

The database looks like this:

```
teams: {
    teamID3ic3kic9w3jkck : {
        userIDs: ["11111", "22222", "33333", "44444"]
        teamData { ....}
    }
}
```

where I want to allow users with an ID matching any of the IDs in the "userIDs" array to access "teamData".  Would really appreciate help figuring this out.

Comment: Please post the rules that you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you're looking to do `array.contains()`, you're likely using the wrong data structure. For example, this seems more like a mathematical *set* to me: an unordered collection of unique items. In Firebase you'd model that as:

```
teams: {
    teamID3ic3kic9w3jkck : {
        userIDs: {
            "11111": true, 
            "22222": true, 
            "33333": true,
            "44444: true"
        ]
        teamData { ....}
    }
}
```

Now you can secure this with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "teams": {
      "$teamid": {
        ".read": {
          ".read": "data.child('userIDs').child(auth.uid).exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```